# Resolving Linux Library Dependencies?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm new to Linux, but I'm trying to distribute an application in .deb and .rpm format.  I'm having trouble with the below three libicu libraries:

```
libicui18n.so.52.1 => not found
libicuuc.so.52.1 => not found
libicudata.so.52.1 => not found
```

The problem is that the version required for the application does not always match the version installed on the system, for example Fedora 26 comes with libicu 57.1 while my application is looking for 52.1.  Adding libicu to the package dependency list doest help, because libicu is already installed, so  installing libicu just gives:

```
Package libicu-57.1-6.fc26.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I couldn't find a package for libicu52.1, but trying to install an older package doesn't seem to work anyway.  I tried `libicu-54.1-4.fc22.x86_64` but it says no package available, presumably because it's only available on Fedora 22.

I was thinking of including the libraries in the application package and having them install to /usr/lib64, but being a Linux newbie I'm unsure if this is an acceptable thing to do.

What's the best way to solve this?

Edit: I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10471907/8483285) post in the related section which says:

> Newer versions of libraries should not break existing apps unless
>   you're using deprecated features.

I'm testing on Fedora 26 which comes with libicu 57.1.  My application only requires libicu 52.1, so if the above is true I assume it should be working.  Is there something I need to do to make it work?

Comment: What about a link to static libraries, if they are available ?

Comment: Containerisation, e,g. https://www.docker.com/

Comment: It appears that libicu can be built for static linking, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426868/dealing-with-library-dependencies-on-linux/10471907#10471907) post static linking is not a good solution and dependency problems are best solved through packaging.  He also recommends against bundling the library, which is what I wanted to do.  Unfortunately I'm not sure how to solve it through packaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having your package install "extra" versions of `libicu` to `/usr/lib64` would be very surprising to most users.  Don't do that.

The standard practice here is to build different .deb and .rpm files per target platform.  The same as you need to build separately for 32-bit vs 64, you need to build separately for, say, CentOS 6 vs 7.  You can do this by running a set of virtual machines to do the release builds--one for each target platform you want to support.

If you truly need to make a single .deb or .rpm that works on many platforms, one way is to eliminate some of your dependencies.  In this case, all those libraries are part of the same project (ICU), so if you don't really need to depend on that project, don't.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question about installing the libraries to `/user/lib64`.  I won't do that.   Doing a build for every distribution every six months seems like a lot of work, and it would be even harder with distros like Arch which are on a rolling model where the packages can change at any time.  If that's the only solution I suppose I'll just have to limit support to a few distributions.  I edited my post after reading one of the questions in the Related column and was wondering if you could tell me, should a program that requires libicu52.1 work on Fedora with libicu57.1?

Comment: @Leagram: In practice, of course you have to limit to a few officially supported distributions.  People using uncommon distros can build from source if they need to (they'll be used to it!).  As for `libicu` 52 vs 57, well, it depends!  There is a whole section labeled Binary Compatibility where that is discussed: http://userguide.icu-project.org/design#TOC-ICU-Binary-Compatibility:-Using-ICU-as-an-Operating-System-Level-Library - if you meet specific requirements you may be able to do it, though you may need a symlink to make the loader find the other version (at runtime or build time).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help.  I decided to follow your earlier suggestion and built Qt with the -no-icu configuration.  I thought this would break Unicode support in my application, but it doesn't appear to have any impact.  The executable now seems to run anywhere, for example the Debian build will run on Fedora and the openSUSE build runs on Debian, which I wasn't expecting and thought I'd have to do at least two builds (Debian and RPM).  I'll do more testing to make sure it works correctly and try it on some other distributions, and if it works I'll release it. Thanks again.